# ExpandableListView change color of child when expand

Tags: colors, expandablelistview

I create an expandablelistview that, when a child is selected, change the color of that to BLUE. When i press it's gonna be ok, but when i rexpand the list another child (the near to the selected) goes BLUE and the selected turn to white? Why? That's the code on ONChilCLickListener

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView l, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                    tipocontrol=0;
                    tipocontrolex=0;
                    for (int i=0; i < l.getChildCount(); i++) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Item: "+l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());       
                    }


                    tipouser=l.getItemAtPosition(childPosition+1).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Child is clicked "+tipouser, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    for(int k=0; k<l.getChildCount(); k++){

                        System.out.println("Exp count Click "+expListView.getChildAt(k).toString());
                        System.out.println("Exp count CLick "+expListView.getItemAtPosition(k).toString()+" position "+k);
                        if(expListView.getItemAtPosition(k).toString().equals(tipouser)){

                            expListView.getChildAt(k).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            System.out.println("Trovato pos exp click"+tipouser+" = "+expListView.getChildAt(k));
                            tipocontrolex=k;
                        }
                        else if(k==0){

                        }
                        else{
                            expListView.getChildAt(k).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            System.out.println("Non selezionato expand click"+expListView.getChildAt(k));

                        }
                    }
                    tipocontrol=childPosition+1;

                    System.out.println("Tipocontrol "+tipocontrol);
                    System.out.println("Tipocontrolex "+tipocontrolex);

        int count =  l.getCount();
                    System.out.println("Count explistview "+l.getCount() );
                    for (int i = 0; i <count ; i++){
                      l.collapseGroup(i);

                    }

                    return false;
                }


            });
```